# can we have a folder called images in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

i used have a folder called images in SharePoint 2010 created from SharePoint Designer as the rootfolder. It is not a library not a list a rootfolder at the top.
I have migrated the whole content database to 2013. 
now i cannot browse anything with in this folder.
If i change the name to images2 then it works else it is not working with the name images. 
is there any new preservation for the names in sp2013.
my folder location ins 2010 was like this sitename/images ( not a library a root folder)
now seems it is not letting me to browse this. 
any idea and workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no we cannot have two folders with same name. 
the problem was there was a folder with same name in the web-root folder and we tried to create another same folder name in the root directory through SharePoint designer which is not correct.